# How do I narrow type with Typescript, considering, that it's a union type, and index is a variable?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, typeerror, narrowing

actionsCollection has union type with similar structure:

`{`

`install: {...}`

`bid: {...}`

`} | {`

`travel: {...}`

`bid: {...}`

`pass: {...}`

`} | ...`

None of the keys in subsets are mandatory or unique.

Here's my code:

`if (`

`!(actionType in actionsCollection) ||`

`('install' in actionsCollection) || // this check has an effect`

`!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(`

`actionsCollection,`

`actionType`

`) ||`

`!Object.keys(actionsCollection).includes(actionType) ||`

`!Object.hasOwn(actionsCollection, actionType)`

`) {`

`return socket!.emit('socketError', ERRORMESSAGES.UNKNOWNACTION);`

`}`

`let ttt = actionsCollection.install; // if I return when ('install' in actionsCollection) is truthful, this line throws an error`

`ttt = actionsCollection[actionType]; // this line always throws an error`

The error says:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"install" | "bid" | "travel" | "pass" | "place" | "concede" | "playcard"' can't be used to index type '{ install: (p: DefaultActionParams & { polynominoId: number; polynominoOrientation: number; polynominoPosition: number; }) => Promise<ProcessPlayerActionReturn>; bid: (p: DefaultActionParams & { ...; }) => Promise<...>; travel: (p: DefaultActionParams & { ...; }) => Promise<...>; pass: (p: DefaultActionParams & { .....'.`
`Property 'place' does not exist on type '{ install: (p: DefaultActionParams & { polynominoId: number; polynominoOrientation: number; polynominoPosition: number; }) => Promise<ProcessPlayerActionReturn>; bid: (p: DefaultActionParams & { ...; }) => Promise<...>; travel: (p: DefaultActionParams & { ...; }) => Promise<...>; pass: (p: DefaultActionParams & { .....'.ts`

In other words, when I check for a presence of a particular string ('install') key, TypeScript reacts.
But how do I let TypeScript know, that actionsCollection can be cast to a certain subset of a union, or at least has actionsCollection as a key?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing, without pseudocode (e.g, `...`) or undeclared types/values (e.g., `socket`) that cause IDE errors.  Also please reformat your code to be readable; put it in one big code block as opposed to a bunch of individual unindented lines.

Comment: Tip: use 3 ` quotes for code blocks, instead of 1. Lookup markdown code blocks for examples

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.